# Htaccess - Redirecionar todas as requisições para um único arquivo sempre

Tags: php, htaccess, apache, url, mod-rewrite

Estou tentando usar um arquivo .htaccess para redirecionar todas as requisições para um único arquivo, mas estou enfrentando alguns problemas.

Meu .htaccess está assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Meu arquivo index.php está no mesmo diretório do arquivo .htaccess, e também tenho nesse mesmo diretório um arquivo pagina1.php. Meu problema está quando acesso:

localhost/pagina1.php

Quando especifico a extensão do arquivo, este é processado, ao invés de redirecionar para o index.php

Como poderia fazer com que mesmo com a extensão a requisição redirecione para o arquivo index.php, sem afetar importações de CSS e JS?

Comment: Dica: A linha `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` serve para verificar se o arquivo existe, caso a condição seja verdadeira, executa-o.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É uma solução meia-boca, você pode encontrar melhores pesquisando no google (E sim, tem, você deveria pesquisar antes de postar pergunta aqui no Stack cara :/ )

Use o seguinte código no seu htaccess

OBS: Se você não tiver muito conhecimento em .htaccess e já estiver usando um, faça backup dele, crie um novo e cole o seguinte nele:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|style\.css|js\.js)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Onde o `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|style\.css|js\.js)` ***ficam os arquivos que não devem sofrer a regra de redirecionamento***, sendo style.css (arquivo.ext) | < Separado de arquivos ou seja `arq\.ext|arq2\.ext` etc....

***Espero que ajude :)***